# json from file to file in same style in oneline per line

Tags: php, json

i wanna convert a json file has text like this design `json_text` https://phponlines.com/result/e2j9RgRnm7

```
$json_text = '
[
{"id": "1", "name": "john", "bd": []},
{"id": "2", "name": "gary", "bd": [1, 2]}
]';
$json_decoded = json_decode($json_text, true);
var_dump(json_encode($json_decoded));
```

then after i edit it to get same design again but i get different deisng instead in one line

```
[{"id":"1","name":"john","bd":[]},{"id":"2","name":"gary","bd":[1,2]}]
```

but what i want is

```
[
{"id": "1", "name": "john", "bd": []},
{"id": "2", "name": "gary", "bd": [1, 2]}
]
```

Comment: There is not a simple/sane way to accomplish this exact format. You can use the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` flag to get a more human-readable formatting, but it ends up more spread out. Is there a certain reason you need this format?

Comment: @Sammitch its readable and less space - when i tried with pretty print it  and size became 100mb to 300mb

Comment: You'll have to do your own formatting , there's nothing built-in that does this. The python code is open source, so you could modify that.

Comment: Readability is not a particularly useful metric for a data serialization format. Pretty printing does indeed add a lot of extra bytes, but they're all whitespace and any form of compression [eg: HTTP compression] renders the size difference a moot point. But there are also client-side tools such as in-browser JSON viewers, various text editors/IDEs for GUI, and jq on the CLI that you can just to expand the compact, efficient format to something nicer for human eyeballs to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my comments above, this is not particularly advisable, and writing any portion of a JSON file by hand is even more inadvisable.

But if you do not wish to see the light, then at least the use the minimal amount of darkness.

```php
// polyfill for PHP<8.1
if (!function_exists('array_is_list')) {
    function array_is_list(array $a)     {
        return $a === [] || (array_keys($a) === range(0, count($a) - 1));
    }
}

function do_weird_json(array $input) {
    if( ! array_is_list($input) ) {
        throw new Exception('Input data must be a list');
    }
    
    return sprintf("[\n%s\n]\n", implode(",\n", array_map('json_encode', $input)));
}

$json_text = '
[
{"id": "1", "name": "john", "bd": []},
{"id": "2", "name": "gary", "bd": [1, 2]}
]';
$json_decoded = json_decode($json_text, true);

$json_decoded[1]['name'] = 'bill';

var_dump(do_weird_json($json_decoded));
```

Output:

```
string(74) "[
{"id":"1","name":"john","bd":[]},
{"id":"2","name":"bill","bd":[1,2]}
]
"
```

Again, the best thing to do would be to leave the JSON as the default, not-human-friendly format and use a client-side tool like `jq`, etc to reformat the JSON for you for viewing purposes.